# Python: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable:

Tags: python

I want to know why appear this error:
Python: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable:

I fighting with this fragment:

```
def numHyM():

    archivo=open("archivoTexto.txt","r") 
    M=[] 
    linea=archivo.readline()
    while linea: 
        M = M + [linea.split] 
        linea=archivo.readline()
        h=0
        for i in range(0,len(M)):
            if M[i][6]=="H":
                h=h+1
                print(h)
    print("IS", h,"man")
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to call the split function on each line so change `M = M + [linea.split]` to `M = M + [linea.split()]`.

```
archivo=open("archivoTexto.txt","r") 
M=[] 
linea=archivo.readline()
while linea: 
    M = M + [linea.split()] 
    linea=archivo.readline()
    h=0
    for i in range(0,len(M)):
        if M[i][6]=="H":
            h=h+1
            print(h)
print("IS", h,"man")
```